# Getting weird results in array-cleanup function

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, newline, associative-array

I have an associative array titled `$allFeeds` (after executing `print_r($allFeeds);`) as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (           

            [feed_status] => Vividly dug<br />Hchxhh civic<br />Hchxhh cuffing<br />Viccydyduiggigig<br />Bivucfigigudufyd<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Jfufjfufigijdgdjcj<br />Crucify fix<br />Ogives gif<br />Gucucvi<br />Jfufjfufigijdgdjcj<br />Juicy fiduciary<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Jcjcufufydxy<br />Igufucuducufuf<br />Jxjdfjdjdj<br />Vuycychxxhgx<br />Ibis figjfhdjhljgh<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Jfufjfufigijdgdjcj<br />Hchxhh chic<br />Jfufjfufigijdgdjcj<br />Hchxchcfzdhfjhgjvjvh<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Hchxhh chic<br />Huhxxgxgxhxjchxhcjhkkbj<br />Hchxhh dhfjgjigk<br />Huffy djcdxjbghc<br />Hchxgxxgxhgxgc<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Hchxhh sha<br />Jhchxhxhchcfchjc<br />Jccchcydfydfy<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Huhxyfgchdjc<br />Jcfhfjfjjf<br />Jcfhfjfjjf

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] => Prodded<br />Fuzhou<br />Chchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg<br />Off finish<br />Hogfish I<br />Ifusudigogig<br />Jfufjfufigijdgdjcj<br />Hxhxhfjfufjf<br />It&#039;s sufficed<br />Hchxhh<br />Hdufjkvhchcfudgfycjufhkjgh<br />

        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] => Jfkfzzogzgi<br />Jffixgoogxgox<br />Kfcjjfgk soffits<br />Dufhfkgk gaits<br />Yahoo googles<br />Kxgzgxgohbjhgfbhjvfdhhcdbkjh<br />

        )

)
```

Now I want to replace `<br />` by `\n` from each of the above values. For that I've written following common function :

```
  function br2nl($buff = '') {
    $buff = mb_convert_encoding($buff, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $buff = preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $buff);
    $buff = trim($buff);

    return $buff;
  }
```

Now to use this function, I've written the below code:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($allFeeds as $key => $value) {
      $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_status']         = br2nl($value['feed_status']);
      $cnt++;
}
```

Now, if I `print_r($allFeeds);` I get below the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (           

            [feed_status] =>              
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] =>             
        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] => 

        )

)
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Can someone please help me out in this issue?

The expected output would be as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (           

            [feed_status] => Vividly dug\nHchxhh civic\nHchxhh cuffing\nViccydyduiggigig\nBivucfigigudufyd\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nJfufjfufigijdgdjcj\nCrucify fix\nOgives gif\nGucucvi\nJfufjfufigijdgdjcj\nJuicy fiduciary\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nJcjcufufydxy\nIgufucuducufuf\nJxjdfjdjdj\nVuycychxxhgx\nIbis figjfhdjhljgh\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nJfufjfufigijdgdjcj\nHchxhh chic\nJfufjfufigijdgdjcj\nHchxchcfzdhfjhgjvjvh\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nHchxhh chic\nHuhxxgxgxhxjchxhcjhkkbj\nHchxhh dhfjgjigk\nHuffy djcdxjbghc\nHchxgxxgxhgxgc\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nHchxhh sha\nJhchxhxhchcfchjc\nJccchcydfydfy\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nHuhxyfgchdjc\nJcfhfjfjjf\nJcfhfjfjjf

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] => Prodded\nFuzhou\nChchcfhdhcjcfufhcjvjgjfhg\nOff finish\nHogfish I\nIfusudigogig\nJfufjfufigijdgdjcj\nHxhxhfjfufjf\nIt&#039;s sufficed\nHchxhh\nHdufjkvhchcfudgfycjufhkjgh\n

        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [feed_status] => Jfkfzzogzgi\nJffixgoogxgox\nKfcjjfgk soffits\nDufhfkgk gaits\nYahoo googles\nKxgzgxgohbjhgfbhjvfdhhcdbkjh\n

        )

)
```

Comment: Why you are using that function just simply use foreach and str_replace  function of PHP

Comment: Code works fine for me! Can't reproduce it.

Comment: But why use function when you are already using foreach. You are making your code complex.Just use single time foreach and get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop, use

```
$allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_status'] = br2nl($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_status']);
```

instead of

```
$allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_status']         = br2nl($value['feed_status']);
```